# Change size of nodes and node label outside of node in tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying t draw a graph with some vertices using tikz, and am using nodes for my vertices. However `\node[circle] (node1) (0,1) {1}` gives a label of 1 inside the node. The node is also quite big. How do I make the node smaller? And how do I put the label outside of the node?

Comment: For example using `\node[circle, inner sep=2pt, label={1}] (node1) at (0,1) {};` (don't forget `at`).

Comment: What do you mean with "quite big". The node size is determined by its shape (here a `circle`), by the inner separators (`/pgf/inner xsep`, `/pgf/inner ysep`, i.e. padding), by the `/pgf/minimum width` and `/pgf/minimum height` and by its content itself or whatever was set via `text width`, `text height` and `text depth`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw, red] (node1) at (0,0) {1};
\node[circle, draw, minimum size=1pt, label={1}] (node1) at (0,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two circles and numbers]